# Null pointer exception in a for loop

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why am i getting this null pointer exception when i execute my for loop?

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
>   A3JPanel.actionPerformed(A3JPanel.java:141) at 
>   javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at 
>   javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source) at 
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
dots[i].moveDots();
}
```

Comment: This is probably because either the `dots` array or one of the elements in it is `null`.  Can you provide more context of the surrounding code so that we can try to see why that might be?

Comment: That's not a null pointer exception. That's a bit of code.

Comment: I'm betting that you've create a dot's array, but you haven't yet filled it with Dot objects. That's my SWAG. Solution, first loop through the array and fill it with new Dot objects.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"     java.lang.NullPointerException
        at A3JPanel.actionPerformed(A3JPanel.java:141)
     at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
     at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)

Comment: The dots are falling dots in a game i am making, when i call the move method on them they update their position. after I run the program and get the null pointer, my window opens, shows the dots draw but they are not moving like they should be.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to initialize each element of the array before you can do operations on them, like this

```
Dot[] dots = new Dot[10];

for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i] = new Dot();
    dots[i].moveDots();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace wasn't very helpful but even if you initialized all your `Dot` objects in the `dot` array, your `moveDots()` method may be responsible for the NullPointerException.  Can you show us a little more of your code so we know where the issue is?  It is obviously not in that little bit you've posted.